# How can I sort Core Data records before GROUP BY?

Tags: ios, core-data

Imagine I have this Core Data entity

```
@objc(SomeEntity)
class SomeEntity: NSManagedObject {
  @NSManaged var date: Date
  @NSManaged var timeZoneIdentifier: String
  @NSManaged var name: String
  @NSManaged var brand: String
}
```

I want to fetch all rows with distinct `name` and `brand` fields, but for each one, I want the *latest* `date` and the `timeZoneIdentifier` for that *latest* `date` row.

Here's some example data:

| date | timeZoneIdentifier | name | brand |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-01-01 | America/Los_Angeles | Name 1 | Brand 1 |
| 2020-01-02 | America/Tiajuana | Name 1 | Brand 1 |
| 2020-01-03 | America/Denver | Name 1 | Brand 2 |
| 2020-01-04 | America/Phoenix | Name 2 | Brand 1 |

I essentially want to fetch `.dictionaryResultType` results that will look like this:

| lastDate | lastDateTimeZoneIdentifier | name | brand |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-01-02 | America/Tiajuana | Name 1 | Brand 1 |
| 2020-01-03 | America/Denver | Name 1 | Brand 2 |
| 2020-01-04 | America/Phoenix | Name 2 | Brand 1 |

Which you could do with this SQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM SomeEntity ORDER BY date DESC) as sub GROUP BY sub.name, sub.brand;
```

Can I achieve the same thing with Core Data with minimal queries? I can't find any examples or documentation online trying to do something like this.

I can write a `NSFetchRequest` that essentially executes this:

```
SELECT date, timeZoneIdentifier, name, brand FROM SomeEntity GROUP BY name, brand ORDER BY date;
```

But that orders after the GROUP BY, not before.

I can also write a `NSFetchRequest` that essentially executes this:

```
SELECT max(date), name, brand FROM SomeEntity GROUP BY name, brand;
```

Which *almost* works only because I wanted the *latest* date, but of course I lose the `timeZoneIdentifier` that the row came from. [I have written up this example as a gist](https://gist.github.com/jmacdonagh/714b52a0f545a65bad26b233cb2315b9) that you can throw into a Swift playground.

Thanks!

Comment: As you’ve probably discovered, you cannot specify any propertiesToFetch other than the properties you group by, and aggregate functions.  Hence you can’t include the timeZoneIdentifier.  However, you can include an NSExpression that represents the evaluated object (see NSExpression.expressionForEvaluatedObject).  This will give you the objectID for the object with the max(date) - which you can then fetch to get the other property values.

Comment: That's it @pbasdf! Two queries instead of O(n). I updated the gist: https://gist.github.com/jmacdonagh/714b52a0f545a65bad26b233cb2315b9. Feel free to submit an actual answer so I can give you credit! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you’ve probably discovered, you cannot specify any `propertiesToFetch` other than the properties you group by, and aggregate functions. Hence you can’t include the `timeZoneIdentifier`.

However, you can include an `NSExpression` that represents the evaluated object (see [`NSExpression.expressionForEvaluatedObject`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsexpression/1411845-expressionforevaluatedobject)). This will give you the objectID for the object with the `max(date)` - which you can then fetch to get the other property values.

Comment: Thank you! For future readers of this question you can see a working solution on my updated gist https://gist.github.com/jmacdonagh/714b52a0f545a65bad26b233cb2315b9