CoreData: Fetching all child entities for a common attribute using polymorphism
I have a Core Data model with an abstract entity called Shape. Shape is a parent entity of Cube, Pyramid, Prism, Cylinder, and Sphere. Each of these individual shapes inherits the volume attribute from the Shape entity
I want to retrieve every child instance of Shape that has the highest volume. However, I want to avoid writing an enum to loop through each and every subclass, as this approach is not maintainable. If a new shape is added later on and the enum is not updated, some Shape entities might be missed.
public enum Shape: CaseIterable {
    case cube
    case pyramid
    case sphere
    case prism
}

Is there a way to leverage polymorphism to fetch all child entities of "Shape" with the highest volume without explicitly enumerating each subclass? This would ensure that the code remains flexible and adaptable to future additions of new shape entities.
I found a similar question that explains how to retrieve child entities alone, but it was asked before the introduction of Swift so the solution is in Objective-C and it's not entirely relevant with what I am trying to achieve. I am interested in a modern approach that leverages polymorphism using Swift.

An answer in Objective-C is totally relevant to Swift, because the Core Data classes and functions are the same.

@TomHarrington I agree with your point. However, I'm not convinced this solution is optimal. By fetching all entities and then filtering them in memory, we might be loading more data than necessary. Utilizing SQLite's capabilities for filtering could potentially offer a more efficient solution - if there's any way to achieve that

@WebStormer there is one possibility, but you have to have an extra attribute name in Shape. First fetch will give objectid based on shape name with high volume as dictionary and another fetch needed for fetching entire objects. are you ok with the extra attribute and two fetches?. check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/65365095/23301405 and the comment also have example
